# Checking with blank(param("some_parameter_name"))) fails with NPE

Tags: activeweb

I tried to check if a mandatory request parameter present with

```
if (blank(param("some_parameter_name"))) {
   // throw SomeException
}
```

and it failed with NPE because:

- in `HTTPSupport#blank(String ... names)` there is a call to `if(Util.blank(param(name)))`
- when calling `param(name)` it returns `RequestUtils.param(name)`;
- in `RequestUtils.param(name)` it fails when calling `if(name.equals("id"))` because `name` parameter is null. Should I open an issue for that ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an incorrect use of the API

Please, use like this:

```
if (blank("param1", "param2",...)) {
   // throw SomeException
}
```

In other words, the method `blank()` expects names of parameters to check.

Check out docs: [HttpSupport.html#blank](http://javalite.github.io/activeweb/snapshot/org/javalite/activeweb/HttpSupport.html#blank-java.lang.String...-)

Comment: Ah, ok my bad, - I believed that I had to pass in `param("some_name")`. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to upcote the answer then:)